# How to return bitmap from child activity in android

Tags: android, bitmap, android-activity

I have tried below code to return bitmap from child activity to parent activity and I am getting null pointer exception,

### Child Activity Code:

```
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    overlayImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
    byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

    Intent intent=new Intent();
    intent.putExtra("overlay",byteArray);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);

    finish();
```

### Parent Activity Code:

```
            protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)           {
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            editorBitmapArray.add(current_bmp);
            byte[] byteArray = getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("overlay");
            current_bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
            Image.setImage(current_bmp);
        }
```

How to return byte array from child activity to parent activity in android?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you should get bitmap by data not getIntent()

```
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)           {
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            editorBitmapArray.add(current_bmp);
            byte[] byteArray = data.getByteArrayExtra("overlay");
            current_bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
            Image.setImage(current_bmp);
        }
```

Comment: Actually, this is not a recommended way,  if the extra size is big, the app could raise exception

Comment: @jacky what's the recommended way? Generate a content URI?

Comment: This way works, if your **Intent data** is not bigger than 1MB

Answer (score 2):

Use `data` instead of `getIntent()` to get `ByteArray` in `onActivityResult` :

```
byte[] byteArray = data.getByteArrayExtra("overlay");
```

Comment: Thanks, you helped me too

Comment: @MarcDiMillo: Sure share question link

Comment: I didn't post a question, but I found it by searching. Didn't know that method existed, I would've just tried serializing a bitmap (in byte array form, from custom camera).